# How to assign output of s:date to a 'var'(s:set) in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, variable-assignment, ognl, struts-tags

I'm looking for:

```jsp
<s:set var="A_VARIABLE" value="<s:date name='OBJECT.MEMBER' format='XXX_FORMAT'/>"/>
```

Then, I want to manipulate `#A_VARIABLE`, but `A_VARIABLE` is not getting value from `s:date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest tags like that. Use `<s:set>` tag with body content. Put your `<s:date>` tag inside `<s:set>` tag.

```
<s:set var="A_VARIABLE">
  <s:date name="OBJECT.MEMBER" format="XXX_FORMAT"/>
</s:set>
```

Comment: Can't believe what I was doing, hit by programmer's block :(

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `value` attribute, like other attributes in Struts2 tags is evaluated as OGNL expression and if it fails leaves the value as is.

The value is also has a meaning if you remove the `value` attribute and use the body of the tag.

You can't nest Struts tags inside Struts tag's attributes.